# How to add a dataset toggle to Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js to create a line chart. I would like to have four different datasets that will all be visibile by default, but can be toggled on and off by clicking a button. How can this be achieved? I can't seem to find an answer in the documentation. `.addData()`, `.removeData()` and `.update()` all seem to be used for adding or removing values to existing datasets, but not adding or removing entire datasets. I would think this would be fairly commonly used feature but I can't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After thoroughly researching this, there doesn't appear to be any built in function to toggle entire datasets. I used the `.destroy()` function to remove the entire existing chart, and then some logic to redraw it with the necessary datasets.

EDIT: Here's a fiddle with my full code if it's helpful to anyone -> http://jsfiddle.net/21xg27kr/4/

Comment: Can you add a link to http://jsfiddle.net/ with a working example? I was not able to get the code to run and I'm trying to do something very smiler.

Thanks

Comment: A bit late, but here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/21xg27kr/4/ I forgot that I incorporated some dashed line functionality from a fork of chart.js that won't work with the default plugin. The fiddle has my full code without the dashed lines.

Comment: I'm getting a "currentChart is not defined" error in the log, any idea what the issue might be @JoshWarren ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a line chart with two datasets. By updating the datasets and calling the `.update()` method. The benefit here is you don't need to destroy the whole chart, and there is a nice animated transition [which can be disabled](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#preventing-animations).

TL:DR; [solution on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o3hkcv5j/5/)

Step by Step:

- Bring in Chart.js from a CDN

  ```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  ```
- Create the HTML Canvas element that will hold the chart

  ```
  <canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
  ```
- Hide/Show buttons for this example
- Creating the chart, and the functions to update it live - notice that the same integer data needs to be copied in two places - in the initial creation, and in the show function.

  ```
   <script>
   lineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
              labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
              datasets: [
                  {
                      label: "Set 1",
                      fill: true,
                      backgroundColor: "rgba(90,181,242,0.2)",
                      borderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
                      pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
                      data: [3, 1, 1, 0]
                  }, {
                      label: "Set 2",
                      fill: true,
                      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
                      borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                      pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                      pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                      data: [1, 3, 3, 5]
                  }
              ]
          },
          options: {
              title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: 'Chart Title'
              }
          }
      });

     function restoreLayer2(){
          lineChart.data.datasets[1].data = [1, 3, 3, 5];
          lineChart.update();
      }

      function removeLayer2() {
          lineChart.data.datasets[1].data = [];
          lineChart.update();
      }
  </script>
  ```

Comment: Your fiddle has a really nice CSS for the buttons, I was wondering how you did that as there seems to be no CSS in the fiddle anywhere?

Comment: The buttons are plain/unstyled, so I'm not sure I understand the question. The animated transition is a feature of chart.js, all you have to do is call `<chartObject>.update()` in your code.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't scroll down in the fiddle and just saw that the legend activated and disabled the lines and assumed that was your code - assuming that there now is a built in function in chart.js for this?

Comment: @user3144201 Yes, the animation is built in. All I did was call `update()` on the chart object.

Comment: I updated this for you: http://jsfiddle.net/wb5tdo1q/2/