# How can I add dataset toggle to Chart.js?

Tags: linechart, chart.js

**GOAL:**    Clicking on `chart` `legend` I want to show/hide corresponding line.
             I am using *Chart.legend.js* to create `legend`. I know [How to add a dataset toggle to Chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026156/how-to-add-a-dataset-toggle-to-chart-js) asked the same question **but** I cannot use jQuery.

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace the jQuery functions in the question you linked to by their Javascript equivalents.

**1.**

> `var ctx = jQuery("#LineChart").get(0).getContext("2d");`

becomes

`var ctx = document.getElementById("LineChart").getContext("2d");`

**2.**

> ```
> SPOn = jQuery('.sp').hasClass('enabled');
> NCOn = jQuery('.nc').hasClass('enabled');
> SPAOn = jQuery('.sp-avg').hasClass('enabled');
> NCAOn = jQuery('.nc-avg').hasClass('enabled');
> ```

becomes

```
SPOn = document.getElementsByClassName('sp')[0].className.indexOf('enabled') != -1;
NCOn = document.getElementsByClassName('nc')[0].className.indexOf('enabled') != -1;
SPAOn = document.getElementsByClassName('sp-avg')[0].className.indexOf('enabled') != -1;
NCAOn = document.getElementsByClassName('nc-avg')[0].className.indexOf('enabled') != -1;
```

**3.**

> `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`

becomes a javascript block before the end of the  tag (there are other ways to do it, but this seemed the easiest to demonstrate)

**4.**

> `jQuery('.chart-toggles a').click(function() {`

becomes

```
function toggleLine(t) {
```

and

```
<a class="sp enabled" onclick="toggleLine(this)">Toggle SP</a>
<a class="nc enabled" onclick="toggleLine(this)">Toggle NC</a>
<a class="nc-avg enabled" onclick="toggleLine(this)">Toggle NC Avg</a>
<a class="sp-avg enabled" onclick="toggleLine(this)">Toggle SP Avg</a>
```

**5.**

> `jQuery(this).toggleClass('enabled');`

becomes

```
if (t.className.indexOf('enabled') == -1)
     t.className += ' enabled'
else
     t.className = t.className.replace('enabled', '');
```

Fiddle with no jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/htc4gyu5/

Notice that I've moved everything to the HTML block - that's mainly for #3 in the above list.

Comment: Thank you @potatopeelings, I update the Whole project http://jsfiddle.net/co3L0bdb/3/ 

You gave me great help, hope to be able to continue developing on my own. Thank you again

Comment: I have a new problem now, when new points are added they do not have the 'pointHighlightFill' and 'pointHighlightStroke' properites.

Comment: this is the update  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/co3L0bdb/3/

as you can see from "2015" dots dont become White when muose is over them.

Comment: I'll take a shot at it. You might want to ask a separate question too btw - I doubt you'll see a lot of folks looking at this question since it's already answered + this is in the comments. Cheers!

Comment: Just add currentChart.datasets.forEach(function(e) { e.points[e.points.length - 1].highlightFill = "#fff" }); after adding your new data. Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hv67rqdt/ (if you need to set any other properties that don't get carried over - just set it in the same function)

Comment: @FabianN. - I rolled back your edit since the quoted code was to make it easy to figure out which code blocks to copy (esp. since there are multiple changes to make). Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings Thanks for fixing it. I kind of got into a "fixed code formatting"-frenzy and with 100 edits per day some mistakes are bound to happen. (I only saw "a list" and "quoted code" and thought someone just couldn't figure out howto format code in a list) Sorry for creating more work for you.

Comment: @FabianN. - no worries. Cheers!